# keypress event not working in IE and Chrome but working in FF

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, keypress

Any idea why this might happen? I would usually think that Chrome would be more forgiving with the codes?

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) rightImage();
    if(e.keyCode == 37) leftImage();
});
```

Thats what my keypress key looks like. Am I missing something? rightImage(); and leftImage(); are functions which should be working becase I'm using those functions somewhere else too

Thanks for the help!

Comment: for me, your keycode 39 is the  ->  ' (quotes)

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/LmXaW/10/

Comment: @RicardoArruda It is using keydown event not keypress.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Change `keypress` to `keydown`:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) rightImage();
    if(e.keyCode == 37) leftImage();
});
```

The keydown event occurs when the key is pressed, followed immediately by the keypress event. Then the keyup event is generated when the key is released.

> In order to understand the difference between keydown and keypress, it
>   is useful to understand the difference between a "character" and a
>   "key". A "key" is a physical button on the computer's keyboard while a
>   "character" is a symbol typed by pressing a button.  In theory, the
>   keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released,
>   while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The
>   implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks guys! yeah keydown works! also thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Ariane I swapped the link with the text of that webpage (that I could retrieve via the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20111114041930/http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer here: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

"If you want to use arrows, delete, backspace keys in Chrome you must use keydown. keypress on these keys work only in Firefox and Opera."

Your code didn't work for me in iE8 (worked in FF), so I switched keypress to keydown. Works in IE now. Don't have Chrome here to test.

Answer (score 0):

yes this can be achieved by changing `onkeypress` event to `onkeydown`. Moreover this issue exists just in case of Internet Explorer when you want to trigger an event on space click.