# Up and down key only work in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I'm writing a script for move in a li element with arrow key :

```
$('#tw_nav').focus(function(){
        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                // User pressed "up" arrow
                case 38:

                break;
                // User pressed "down" arrow
                case 40:

                break;
                // User pressed "enter"
                case 13:

                break;
            }
        });
    });
```

So, when i test this code with firefox, it's ok, i can get cases 38 (up), 40(down) and 13(enter). but with safari, chrome or ie, this code doesn't work.... Any ideas ?

Comment: As you're using jQuery, use `event.which` for the key-code.

Comment: hopefully onblur you are removing the keypress event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [keypress event not working in IE and Chrome but working in FF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311290/keypress-event-not-working-in-ie-and-chrome-but-working-in-ff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [keydown()](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event along with [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) property:

```
$('#tw_nav').keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        // User pressed "up" arrow
        case 38:
            alert('Up arrow pressed');    
            break;
        // User pressed "down" arrow
        case 40:
            alert('Down arrow pressed');      
            break;
        // User pressed "enter"
        case 13:
            alert('Enter pressed');     
            break;
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ny6cw/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $('#tw_nav').keypress(function(e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery. use `e.which`

```
$('#tw_nav').keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        // User pressed "up" arrow
        case 38:

        break;
        // User pressed "down" arrow
        case 40:

        break;
        // User pressed "enter"
        case 13:

        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: it should be `keydown()` not `keypress()`